# Ошибка при помещении двоичного числа в переменную с типом данных long

Tags: java

Когда я присваиваю переменной с типом данных long двоичное число, к примеру -‭ 0111010110111100110100010101‬ (123456789), то компилятор ругается и выдает ошибку.

Скриншот - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код:

```
    long l1 = 123456789L;
    long l2 = 0x75BCD15L;
    long l3 = 0726746425L;
    long l4 = ‭0b0111010110111100110100010101‬L;

    System.out.println(l1 + ", " + l2 + ", " + l3 + ", " + l4 + ".");
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем именно проблема?

Answer (score 6):

IDEA говорит, что у вас после `l4 =` символ [`U+202D`](https://unicode-table.com/en/202D/) вместо пробела (который выглядит как пробел, но им не является). Удалите его и поставьте пробел.

Также перед L в строке с `l4` непечатаемый символ [`U+202C`](https://unicode-table.com/en/202C/), его нужно удалить (его не видно, но он там есть).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эти символы могли попасть в код, если вы копировали его с какого-нибудь сайта. Если вводить вручную, то таких проблем не должно возникать.

Answer (score 2):

Мой вариант является полностью рабочим. Пожалуйста, скопируйте и вставьте его, потому что в вашем присутствует скрытый символ, который мешает нормально закомпилить программу.

```
long l1 = 123456789L;
long l2 = 0x75BCD15L;
long l3 = 0726746425L;
long l4 = 0b0111010110111100110100010101L;

System.out.println(l1 + ", " + l2 + ", " + l3 + ", " + l4 + ".");
```

Вывод:

```
 123456789, 123456789, 123456789, 123456789.
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не получилось.

Comment: Можете здесь [протестировать](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler). Видимо с настройками IDEA что-то не так.

Comment: Да, тут работает. Видимо, проблема в IDE. Спасибо за подсказку и помощь!

Comment: Попробуйте скопировать мой код, который в ответе и вставьте в свою программу.

Comment: Да, при копировании заработало. Не подскажете, как избежать подобных проблем в будущем?

Comment: Честно даже не подскажу, но есть подозрение, что у вас там какой-то скрытый символ был, наверное, скопировали код откуда-то или по случайности получилось.